# Button backgrounds overlap with the border on tag tab

Tags: bug, design

The buttons *info*, *newest*, *featured*, *frequent*, *votes* and *active* on the tab below the Stack Overflow menu are overlapping with the border on the background, resulting in ugly dashes as can be seen in the image below.

**Browser**: Chrome, Microsoft Edge
**OS**: Windows 10
**Resolution**: 1920x1080

[image: Screenshot with freehand circles and arrows highlighting the overlapping borders]

Border connects (only over the button) when I put my mouse over it.

[image: Screenshot with freehand circle and arrows highlighting a button in its hovered state]

---

I just realized it exists on screenshots from some other questions as well, and I've never realized it was like this before, but maybe it is a feature, not a bug? If so, I think it looks ugly :/

---

**Edit (19/01/2018):** They removed the line and "Public questions tagged [python]" label, it is now "Tagged Questions". Looks much better and less OCD inducing, thanks!
[image]

Comment: Hm, that's new... Reproduced on the latest chrome here.

Comment: I only saw because of the awesome freehand circle. Reproduced on IE 11(.192.16299.0) and Chrome 63(.0.3239.132).