# Line under the feature tab button missing

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

The *feature* button on the tag tab is missing the bottom line. All other buttons seems to be correct, with the line removed only for the active tab.

**Browser**: Chrome 63.0.3239.132
**OS**: Windows 7
**Screen resolution**: 1366x768

Screenshot for reference:
[image]

Hovering over the *feature* tab will make the line appear:

[image]

Related, but slightly different question: [Button backgrounds overlap with the border on tag tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362181/button-backgrounds-overlap-with-the-border-on-tag-tab)

**Update:** The problem is still present. I have tried changing the screen resolution since others have reported the same issue with different levels of zoom, but it didn't help. Clearing the browser cache did not help either. I can't reproduce the issue using IE 11 on the same computer so it is possible it is something Chrome specific.

**Update 2:** The issue is not limited to the *feature* tab. It seems that tabs with the **blue box** containing a number are missing the line in question. The *responses* and *reputation* tabs in the profile:

[image]

Comment: no repro in chrome, windows here...[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2fS1.png)

Comment: Using Firefox on Windows, I notice the line disappears when you zoom out. It reappears when you refresh the page or zoom in to 100% again.

Comment: @Stijn: For me it's gone at 100% zoom, but it reappears and looks ok at 125%.  At 175% the line disappears from the other buttons as well.

Comment: For the record, zooming in our out is not supported, only when you have issues at 100% you can report them (which is the case here).

Comment: @Stijn: I didn't know that. I will roll back the question to the previous version.

Comment: I get the behaviour you describe on 90% zoom, but normal on 100%. Chrome 63.0.3239.108 on Ubuntu 16.04 with a 1080p monitor.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this on Chrome, at 100%:

> [image]

<strike>This is not really a "bug": Only a zoom level of 100% is supported.</strike>

Use different zoom levels at your own "risk".

Comment: I didn't know that zoom is not supported, I have rolled back the question to the previous version (only mentioning the issue with the feature tab without zooming).

Comment: Okay, did you clear your cache, @Shaido?

Comment: Yes, I tried that however it didn't help.

Comment: Zoom is not optional. It must be supported!

Comment: @dfeuer: So, what zoom levels? 50%? 49%? 200%? 23.5%? It's unrealistic to expect a site to display properly at every soom level / resolution combination.

Comment: @Cerbrus, no, but only supporting 100% seems pretty unreasonable too.

Comment: @dfeuer So, post a feature request to expand support for other zoom levels. This answer is as it is right now. What you think "should" be the case doesn't change how the site works _now_.